# which meaning of "then" fits here?

Tags: meaning

Perhaps there is a retired plod with a 50-year-old duty roster that can give us a more definitive idea of how officers **then** spent their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of your sentence

> how officers **then** spent their time

means

> how officers spent their time **in those days**

or

> how officers **in the twentieth century** spent their time

where **then** refers to a *time in the past*. This is the first definition in the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/then).

Comment: Do you know which meaning of dictionary is fits here?

Comment: @Kris - edited.